# Is there a way or alternative function to have a vectorized str_detect() in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame with a column of Strings for which I try to filter out the Strings with dates in them.

| ID | headline | SOURCE | domain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Cool text with a date 20.01.2009 | 0 | howtomakelessthanminimumwagebybuyingthisbook.com |
| 22 | not so cool text without date | 0 | lars.com |
| 23 | also a cool text but without a date :( | 0 | somecryptostuff.com |
| 24 | long text with a date like this 3. march 2021 | 0 | blockchainmasterclassforpeoplewithouttechnicalbackground.com |
| 25 | other long text with this kind of date in the text 03/21/99 and other stuff afterwards | 0 | someother.url |

I have written the code to do so.

First, I filter the df for all rows with dates in them using `str_detect()`.

**The code looks like this:**

```
data <- origin%>%
  filter(str_detect(headline, yyyy_mm_dd)|
         str_detect(headline, mm_dd_yyyy)|
         str_detect(headline, mm_dd_yy)|
         str_detect(headline, dd_mm_yyyy)|
         str_detect(headline, dd_mm_yy)|
         str_detect(headline, annoying_dates)|
         str_detect(headline, monthnum_year)|
         str_detect(headline, monthname_year)|
        str_detect(headline," 20(1|2)\\d\\s"))
```

`mm_dd_yyyy` etc. are variables to which I assigned regex. They look like the last line.

My code works fine, but am using these filter criteria quite often and it's kind of annoying and surely not good practice to use a function repetitively.

I was trying to come up with a better solution but ultimately failed to do so. Do you guys have an idea? I thought of using a vector trough which I could loop, but I didn't know if this was possible with `str_detect`

Comment: You could combine the individual regular expressions into one by wrapping each individual expression into `(…)` and concatenating them with a `|` separator.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I‘ve tried that before but I had a lot of unreasonable issues doing so. For some reason, splitting up the regex fixed the bug where it would not match correctly. I tested it on regex101, where it worked but with r it was broken

Comment: Can you show the expected output for the data shared? Also, It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example which can be copied directly into R. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: str_detect is vectorized already, the title is inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

If you work with the `{tidyverse}` family, note that `{lubridate}` has a pretty powerful function: `parse_date_time()`. The latter conveniently "extracts" dates from arbitrary strings.

**data**

```
library(tibble)
ds <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID,  ~headline, ~SOURCE, ~domain
,  21L, "Cool text with a date 20.01.2009", 0L,             "howtomakelessthanminimumwagebybuyingthisbook.com",
  22L, "not so cool text without date", 0L, "lars.com",
  23L, "also a cool text but without a date :(", 0L, "somecryptostuff.com",
  24L, "long text with a date like this 3. march 2021", 0L, "blockchainmasterclassforpeoplewithouttechnicalbackground.com",
  25L, "other long text with this kind of date in the text 03/21/99 and other sutff afterwards", 0L, "someother.url"
  )
```

**parse date (time)**

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

ds %>% 
  mutate(
    DATE  = lubridate::parse_date_time(headline, orders = c("dmy","mdy"))
  , DATE2 = lubridate::parse_date_time(headline, orders = c("dmy","mdy")) %>%    
                                         as.Date() #if you want a "date" only
  ) %>% 
select(headline, DATE, DATE2)
```

`{lubridate}` will throw a warning for the headlines with no Date stating that it failed to parse that headline (without a date). You can possibly wrap this into a call handling the NA case.

This is what you get:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  headline                                                                               DATE                DATE2     
  <chr>                                                                                  <dttm>              <date>    
1 Cool text with a date 20.01.2009                                                       2009-01-20 00:00:00 2009-01-20
2 not so cool text without date                                                          NA                  NA        
3 also a cool text but without a date :(                                                 NA                  NA        
4 long text with a date like this 3. march 2021                                          2021-03-03 00:00:00 2021-03-03
5 other long text with this kind of date in the text 03/21/99 and other sutff afterwards 1999-03-21 00:00:00 1999-03-21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either paste all the regexes with the `|` separator or use a loop function:

```
reduce(purrr:map(c(regex1, regex2, ..., " 20(1|2)\\d\\s"), str_detect(.x, headline))), `|`)
```

```
str_detect(headline, paste(regex1, regex2, ..., " 20(1|2)\\d\\s"), collapse="|")
```